# Can matplotlib library tell me the function of the data that I have passed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am successfully able to create a scatter plot using matplot library in python. I want to know the function that will exist from the data that I have passed (created by program). Basically a function from graph kind of like getting function from data. As per my scatterplot, it is more of an exponential function, not a straight regression line (y = mx+b). Basically looking for function (NOT line) of best fit. Suggestions??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be looking into the curve-fitting problem. There are multiple numerical methods to extract the BEST FIT function. SciPy has a `curve_fit` method to find the best fit using the least squared method.